# Rendered JavaScript from C# for Google Maps does not place markers

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I have a pretty generic piece of JS in the header, which initalises the map and places a marker on it. It looks like so:

```
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Exo:800' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<!--<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.6/jquery.min.js"></script>-->
<script type ="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jqueryslidemenu.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery.jdpicker.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places&sensor=false"></script>
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<script>
    function initialize() {
        var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-33.8688, 151.2195);
        var mapOptions = { zoom: 15, center: myLatlng, mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP }

        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), mapOptions);

        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({ position: myLatlng, map: map });
</script>
```

It sits in the header and works perfectly fine.

However, when I try to generate another one of these scripts using C# now so that I could place markers based on search results, my generated JS breaks after the

```
var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-33.8688, 151.2195);
```

line. That is, no alerts popup after that line when I put them in code to debug.

What am I doing wrong? It's driving me crazy, appreciate any help anyone can offer.

Thank you in advance.

Regards,
Kostya.

Comment: Where is the second one script ? and where is the html part with the 'map_canvas' ?

Comment: Please post the javascript that **doesn't** work. There is nothing to debug in the one that works.

Comment: there are two issues in the code above, 1) initialize() - is not closed and You didn't call the function onload !

Answer (score 0):

You forgot a semi-colon when you declared your options:

```
var mapOptions = { zoom: 15, center: myLatlng, mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP };
```

That usually throws an error for me.